# Textview that allow a text to go below peer Textview from second line in andorid

Tags: android, android-layout

This is what I want to ultimately achieve:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO61r.jpg]

How can we achieve this kind of layout, something like text wrapping to other textview?

Below is my current layout but that is not expected:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="52dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="18dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/add_ticket_hint_gray"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="17dp"
        android:paddingTop="17dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_job_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/app_blue"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="@color/add_ticket_hint_gray"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="17dp"
        android:paddingTop="17dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:minEms="2"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="x2"
            android:textColor="@color/fix_job_price_light_gray"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@color/add_ticket_hint_gray"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:paddingBottom="17dp"
        android:paddingTop="17dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_job_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:minEms="3"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="$1"
            android:textColor="@color/fix_job_opt_gray"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This layout does not allow me to show text below the other textview after the second line.

Comment: What have you done yet? Please add at least a snipped code, research links,... .

Comment: yes, i have added a snipped code

Comment: please be clear what you want, as comments in answer are different. EDIT your question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you want this

```
 <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="360dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="#ff0000"
      android:id="@+id/page1"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Textview-1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="tab-1 content"/>
  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="360dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="#00ff00"
      android:id="@+id/page2"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Textview-2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="tab-2 content"/>
  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="360dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="#0000ff"
      android:id="@+id/page3"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Textview-3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="tab-3 content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="360dp"
      android:layout_height="31dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="119.3dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Textview-1"/>
      <View
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="119.3dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Textview-2"/>
      <View
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="119.3dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:text="Textview-3"/>
      <View
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and change the visible when people click the button

Comment: there is no "\n" in text, if text is not fit in allotted area then its goes to next line that is normal behavior but now i want from second line text goes below other 2 text view as well.

Comment: I change my commit as you picture draws.Wish to help ^0^

Comment: If you want the clicklistener code ,I can show you  the whole code.

Comment: Here, i can understand that you xml layout is to show full content of perticular textview in bottom of frame layout by clicking on it. am i right?
if yes then you are not clear with requirement.

Comment: No, my code can work as you draw, frame can't be click. I did it before two years because my company needed this effect.

Comment: can you please provide me complete working code. so it will be more helpful to me.

Comment: I have updated screen shot so may you get more clear with requirements.

Comment: If I do, I will add "\n" between '6' and '7' , you can also insert a "/n" between the sixth word and the seventh word , or calculate 6 by the width of the top view(this may be what you wanted).By the way ,there is no speacial textview provided by android that can work as you drew.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:text="Textview - 1"
    android:background="#aa0000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#aaaa00"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/container"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/container"
    android:text="Textview - 3"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aa00aa"
        android:text="Textview - 2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/container"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv3"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This not a working, text of "container" textview is hide under other 2 textview.

Comment: You can use \n between first and second line. It will prevent text (first line) from going below the other two textviews

Comment: where i need to add "\n" in original text how can we decide that? as we are size of device, its not like we add \n after few fix chars.